# he was very annoyed

Tags: meaning, adverbs, time, intensifiers

a. He was very much annoyed.

b. He was annoyed much.

c. He was annoyed very much.

I think (b) and (c) sound a bit strange.

I think (b) and (c) could mean that he was **often** annoyed. I think could refer to a single incident as well.

d. He was annoyed much when he leaned that his son was arrested.

e. He was annoyed very much when he leaned that his son was arrested.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct.

You cannot follow **He was annoyed** just with the word **much** although, strangely, you can say that **He was much annoyed**, meaning **very annoyed**.

To say:: **He was annoyed much.** leaves the reader wondering **much what?**

But **much** can follow **He was annoyed** when it modifies something else. For example:

**He was annoyed much more often than I expected.**

Your examples **d.** and **e.** are constructed in similar vein.

Both are legitimate although **d.** definitely reads more easily when **much** precedes annoyed. Most English speakers would probably reverse the word order in **e.** as well. But that's not to say that it's wrong, just a little unusual.

Having said that, it's possibly to use the adverb **muchly** before or after **annoyed** although, as most dictionaries point out, it's generally in informal or humorous contexts.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/muchly

Comment: Although you *can* say something like "Are you annoyed much?" to mean "Are you particularly annoyed?", and I do find [one example of "He was annoyed much by the (etc.)"](https://books.google.com/books?id=8upVSzNeb_cC&pg=RA2-PP26&dq=%22annoyed+much%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi8_63E35T3AhVfj3IEHVN8CMgQ6AF6BAgCEAI)